# How to fix the proxy setup issue with flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, proxy, cross-platform, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter. We have a proxy setup in the network. The proxy is already applied to android studio and it is working fine. While creating a new application it is working fine. But, get packages is not working. It returns

`Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".`

`pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...'`

`set https_proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@hostname:port' I tried this code. Even though it is not working`

Get packages is not working

Answer (score 9):

You need to run these 2 lines on both your Flutter folder and your project folder:

```
set https_proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@hostname:port
set http_proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@hostname:port
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with setting the correct environment variables at the current user scope only (not at "machine" level). Add `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY`.

[image]

Since I have to switch those variables in my laptop everytime I'm outside my job, I've made these script for Powershell.

#### Add Variables

File name: `proxy-variables-add.ps1`

```
Write-Host "ADDING VARIABLES"

# Define your environment variables here
$EnvVariable1 = "http://10.1.33.254:80"
$EnvVariable2 = "http://10.1.33.254:80"
$EnvVariable3 = "localhost,127.0.0.1,::1,LOCALHOST"

# Set environment variables for the current user
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", $EnvVariable1, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", $EnvVariable2, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NO_PROXY", $EnvVariable3, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)

# Display a message to confirm that the variables have been set
Write-Host "Environment USER variables have been set:"
Write-Host "HTTP_PROXY = $EnvVariable1"
Write-Host "HTTPS_PROXY = $EnvVariable2"
Write-Host "NO_PROXY = $EnvVariable3"

# Notify the user to restart applications to apply the changes
Write-Host "Please restart any applications that need to use the new environment variables."
```

#### Remove Variables

File name: `proxy-variables-remove.ps1`

```
Write-Host "REMOVING VARIABLES"

# Define your environment variables here
$EnvVariable1 = $null
$EnvVariable2 = $null
$EnvVariable3 = $null

# Set environment variables for the current user
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", $EnvVariable1, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", $EnvVariable2, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NO_PROXY", $EnvVariable3, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)

# Display a message to confirm that the variables have been set
Write-Host "Environment USER variables have been set:"
Write-Host "HTTP_PROXY = null (and variable deleted)"
Write-Host "HTTPS_PROXY = null (and variable deleted)"
Write-Host "NO_PROXY = null (and variable deleted)"

# Notify the user to restart applications to apply the changes
Write-Host "Please restart any applications that need to use the new environment variables."
```

---

From *bash*, you can run those scripts with the following code, at `.bashrc`:

```bash
# Colors
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
YL='\033[0;33m' # Yellow

function proxyshell {
    currentFolder=$(pwd)
    cd "$HOME/my-scripts/powershellFolder" || exit
    
    if [ "$1" == "on" ]; then
        printf "${YL}>> Running Script\n${NC}"
        echo ""
        powershell -File proxy-variables-add.ps1
        cd "$currentFolder"  || exit
        return 1
    fi

        if [ "$1" == "off" ]; then
        printf "${YL}>> Running Script\n${NC}"
        echo ""
        powershell -File proxy-variables-remove.ps1
        cd "$currentFolder"  || exit
        return 1
    fi
}
```

In the command line, for setting up the environment variables:

```
$ proxyshell on
```

```
$ proxyshell off
```

#### Result

[image]