# when we run flutter doctor these error occured in HTTP Host Availability

Tags: flutter

HTTP Host Availability
X HTTP host "https://cocoapods.org/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Failed host lookup: 'cocoapods.org'
X HTTP host "https://maven.google.com/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Failed host lookup: 'maven.google.com'
X HTTP host "https://pub.dev/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Failed host lookup: 'pub.dev'
X HTTP host "https://cloud.google.com/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Failed host lookup: 'cloud.google.com'

Comment: Does your  internet connection working properly?

Comment: Are you behind some kind of proxy? See for example this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59393300/20444